# WPF - MVVM - UserControl binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

I'm trying to realize a simple example of a UserControl, showing in a TextBox the current DateTime, updated four times each second.

I create a simple user control:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UC.TestUC"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UC"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="100">
    <d:UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:TestUC_VM/>
    </d:UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid Background="Azure">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding TestString}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Where its ViewModel is:

```
namespace UC
{
    public class TestUC_VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _testString;
        public string TestString
        {
            get => _testString;
            set
            {
                if (value == _testString) return;
                _testString = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public TestUC_VM()
        {
            TestString = "Test string.";
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

MainWindow XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="UC.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UC"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="100" Width="200">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindow_VM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:TestUC_VM x:Key="TestUC_VM"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <local:TestUC DataContext="{StaticResource TestUC_VM}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And its ViewModel:

```
namespace UC
{
    public class MainWindow_VM
    {
        public TestUC_VM _uc_VM;

        public MainWindow_VM()
        {
            _uc_VM = new TestUC_VM();
            Task.Run(() => ChangeString());
        }

        public async Task ChangeString()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _uc_VM.TestString = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
                await Task.Delay(250);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Even though I see with debugger that I'm passing through the TestString setter, the MainWindow is not updated.
I'm quite sure I'm missing something trivial in setting DataContext of UC in MainWindow, but I've not been able to find what after several hours of browsing and thinking.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try this in the setter: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TestString));`

Comment: @praty: nothing changes.

Comment: As a note, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext, as you do in your UserControl's XAML. You should remove that.

Comment: @grandangelo Also edit this: `<TextBox Text="{Binding TestString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Besides that, the TestUC_VM member of the MainWindow_VM is not identical to the TestUC_VM resource in the MainWindow, to which you assign the UCs DataContext.

Comment: @praty: nothing changes.

Comment: @Clements: accepted your answer, that was exactly my issue. About setting the DataContext in UserControl, I used the "d:" namespace as I've been suggested in WPF chat.

Comment: Also note that you would typically not make the UserControl know any particalur view model at all. It should instead expose a (bindable) dependency property, which would be bound to a view model property like `<local:TestUC MyString="{Binding UcVm.TestString}">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
<local:TestUC DataContext="{StaticResource TestUC_VM}"/>
```

assigns the value of the TestUC_VM resource to the UserControl's DataContext. This is a different object than the `_uc_VM` member of the main view model, which you are later updating.

Turn the member into a public property

```
public TestUC_VM UcVm { get; } = new TestUC_VM();
```

and write

```
<local:TestUC DataContext="{Binding UcVm}"/>
```

Update the view model like this:

```
UcVm.TestString = ...
```