# WPF mvvm View won't update when called from different ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, viewmodel

I've been trying to update a property inside a usercontrol with it's own VM.

`<Label Content="{Binding Path =LabelText ,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }" Grid.Column="0"/>`

The Label itself works when I set it's text in the VM's constructor, and also updates if I use a command within the VM.

But changing it from outside won't do anything:

```
        private LabelTextBoxVM _testThing;
        public LabelTextBoxVM TestThing
        {
            get => _testThing;
            set
            {
                _testThing = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("TestThing");
            }
        }

           private void Update()
        {
            TestThing.LabelText = "Eureka";
            TestThing.TextBoxText = "Wooosh";
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TestThing");
        }
```

From all I've read, calling NotifyPropertyChanged for TestThing should update the content of both Label and Textbox, but nothing happens.

Comment: I think you need to implement notifypropertychanged for LabelText and TextBoxtext too

Comment: The problem is "*a usercontrol with its own VM*". A UserControl should no have its own, private view model instance that is disconnected from the view model structure of the application. It should instead get its view model (or more precisely the source object of the Bindings of its properties) by inheriting the value of its DataContext property from its parent element, e.g the Window or Page that it lives in.

Comment: @Clemens Can you pint me to a source of how to actually implement something like that? Cause my solution is the product of looking for guides and apparently I'm still wrong.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you need. You don't need to "implement" anything, just use the framework's features. Maybe look at how to declare dependency properties in [Control authoring overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/control-authoring-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). As another note, setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` in the Label's Content Binding is pointless. It has no effect in a OneWay Binding, and has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event.

Answer (score 0):

@Clemens

I found the answer, provided by you actually, in another question:

[wpf-mvvm-usercontrol-binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55219357/wpf-mvvm-usercontrol-binding)

I have to set my DataContext in the parent view, binding to a property in the parent, and delete the Datacontext inside the childVM

So:

`<myViewes:UserControlName DataContext="{Binding VMProperty}/>"`

And this part cannot be in my UserControls:

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
        <viewModels:UserControlVM/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

I am guessing this was what you meant by "inheriting" the VM

Thank you!